# How to Multiply Long by Double

Tags: c#, double, rounding, long-integer, multiplication

Sorry for asking such a beginner question but I can't figure this out.

I have a long integer that I'd like to divide by 1.28 then round it up or down to the nearest integer.

```
long size = 24524343254;
double ratio = 1.28;
size = size * 1.28; //Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'long'
```

Comment: What type of rounding do you want performed?

Comment: Your text and your code disagree. The text says divide, the code does multiply.

Comment: Please don't add things like "C#" to the ends of your questions. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the double result back to long (as the compiler states - there is not implicit conversion):

```
size = (long)Math.Round(size * 1.28);
```

You need `Math.Round` if you want to round to nearest (there is a special case for when the number to round is halfway between two numbers, then it's rounded towards the nearest even by default). You can also simply cast the result back `(long)(size * 1.28)` if you only want to round towards 0.

As pointed out by @CodeInChaos the implicit cast from long to double (`size * 1.28` will cast `size` into a double first) can result in the loss of precision as [doubles only have a precision of 53 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) but long is 64bit.

Comment: `Math.Round` uses Bankers' Rounding (rounds to nearest even) by default.

Comment: @Cameron: This only applies mid point rounding (`1.1` is still rounded to `1` and not `2`)

Comment: It's important to note, that the implicit cast from `long` to `double` is lossy. `double` has 53 mantissa bits, whereas `long` has 63.

Comment: @ChrisWue: Yes; my comment is misleading! Still, it's important to be aware of.

Comment: @Cameron: Yeah, there are many hidden traps when dealing with conversion between floating point and int. Almost surprising that in 99.9% of all cases the result is what you expect - unfortunately the other 0.1% are the bugs in your application.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast result as long.

```
size = (long)Math.Round(size * 1.28);
```

Comment: That doesn't do the rounding.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using `decimal`.

```
size = (long)Math.Round(size * 1.28m);//note the m making the literal a decimal.
```

This offers two advantages over `double` in this situation:

- `decimal` can represent every `long` value exactly (Unlike `double` which only has 53 mantissa bits, decimal has >90 mantissa bit, with is enough to represent the 63 bits used by `long`)
- it can represent 1.28 exactly.

You should also make sure, that `MidpointRounding.ToEven` is fine for you. It rounds `1.5` to `2`, but `0.5` to `0`.

When using `Decimal` casting to `long` if the value is outside the range of `long` will cause an exception.

When using `double` overflow behavior depends on the mode. If you're in a `checked` section, it will throw an exception, in an `unchecked` context it will result in an undefined value. Since undefined values are rarely desirable, I recommend using `checked` with `double`:

```
size = checked((long)Math.Round(size * 1.28));
```